# execution of command from python fails

Tags: python, cmd, operating-system

I do not know why the execution of the command from python does not work. I tried allot to find a solution in the web but this should work, but it does not. the programm Mailalert gives an error "attached file not found."
the attached file path is the file after the "-a"

```
def csv_senden():
    shutil.copyfile(r'\\datenspeicher2\public\Produktion\\Normteilbestellung\MailAlert_CW500_Bestellung.ini', 'C:\\MailAlert\\MailAlert.ini')
    cmd = 'cmd /c "MailAlert  -s "Neue Normteile in Bestellanforderungsliste für KT" -b "@\\DATENSPEICHER2\\public\\Produktion\\Normteilbestellung\\E-Mailtext_CW500.html"  -a "\\DATENSPEICHER2\\public\\Produktion\\Normteilbestellung\\Bestellungen\\Normteilbestellung_CW500_%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%.csv"  "'
    returned_value = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)  # returns the exit code in unix
    print('returnvalue of Mailalert (Codeschluessel see Readme Mailalert) :', returned_value)
    return
```

If I enter following command in the cmd-Window everything works perfectly fine:

```
'cmd /c "MailAlert  -s "Neue Normteile in Bestellanforderungsliste für KT" -b "@\\datenspeicher2\\public\\Produktion\\Normteilbestellung\\E-Mailtext_CW500.html"  -a "\\datenspeicher2\\public\\Produktion\\Normteilbestellung\\Bestellungen\\Normteilbestellung_CW500_%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%.csv"  "'
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I noticed that somehow the command works but not properly. It gives an error back from the MailAlert program back, that says, that the attached file could not be found. Howerver when I enter the command in the cmd Window it workds perfektly as said

Comment: Finally I figured out, that for whatever reason it should be instead of ```\\datenspeicher2\\``` , ```//datenspeicher2\\```. Now it works.